# Libgdx aligning Bitmap font to top right of the screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So since I seem to can't put font into a Table and expand it to top and right, I wonder what is the solution to draw fonts on top right of the screen.

I'm trying with this:

```
highScoreFont.draw(batch, "" + getHighScore, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 1070, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 650);
```

which aligns it perfectly when I'm testing it on my Xperia Z1 which has resolution of 1920x1080. But when I test it on Nexus S which is 800x400 the alignment is completly wrong, the font draws itself in the on the bottom left part of the screen.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Using scene2d, you can use a BitmapFont with Tables, you just need to use a Label, not the BitmapFont directly.

```
BitmapFont font = ...;
Label label = new Label(new LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE));
Table table = new Table();
table.add(label).expand().top().right();
```

This is preferred, as scenes will size to your device and you won't have to worry about the device's screen size.

Using Gdx.graphics.getWidth() returns the device's width, not necessarily your viewport's width, so positioning elements using that value will result in inconsistencies across devices. Hardcoding positions typically becomes very difficult to maintain, but if you want to go this route I'd suggest looking into positioning elements based on the viewport size, not the value returned from Gdx.graphics.